# How to send selected date of rich:calendar to my bean?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces calendar in my JSF 1.1 project. If I select a date, I want to send the selected date to my bean. How can I do it? I write simple code for this but it comes always null.

Here is my JSF page:

```
<rich:panel style="width: 15%;">
    <rich:calendar cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" value="#{functions.selectedDate}"
        datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" style="width:200px;">
    </rich:calendar>
</rich:panel>
```

Here is my bean:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class functions {

    private Date selectedDate;

    public Date getSelectedDate() {
        return selectedDate;
    }

    public void setSelectedDate(Date selectedDate) {
        this.selectedDate = selectedDate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a `<h:form>` and submit it by a command button/link inside the same form.

E.g.

```
<rich:panel style="width: 15%;">
    <h:form>
        <rich:calendar cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" value="#{functions.selectedDate}"
            datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" style="width:200px;">
        </rich:calendar>
        <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{functions.submit}" />
    </h:form>
</rich:panel>
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    System.out.println("Selected date is: " + selectedDate);
}
```

Comment: thnx balusC. ı have to use commandbutton for this ? hmmm maybe rich calendar has a property, ı dont know. ı shouldnt use a button :(

Comment: Then use `onchange="submit()"` or `<a4j:support>`. The whole point is just that you need to submit the data to the server.

Comment: how can ı use onchange="submit()". sorry ı dont understand

Comment: Just add `onchange="submit()"` to `<rich:calendar>`. Or nest `<a4j:support>` inside `<rich:calendar>`. See also RichFaces documentation.

Comment: I'm quite confused by this example. What value/call does rich:calendar make on calling a `<h:commandButton />` (most likely _outside_ the rich:calendar, so that this is part of a larger `<h:form/>` or how do I get the information out of the request?

Comment: @Rob: RichFaces 3.x calendar doesn't auto-submit the data. You've to add a command button and press it afterwards.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry for being unprecise here. Is there a way to "attach" the calendar data to another h:commandButton? Like `<h:commandLink styleClass="button2" action="#{NewsBean.save}" value="Save and Publish">
  <f:param name="?myCalendar?" value="?noIdea?"/>
</h:commandLink>`

Comment: This is actually a different question than the one asked by OP.