# why does rich:calendar not submit any data?

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

I've got a `rich:calendar` and want it to update the attribute `selectedDate` in the managed bean `NewTimeRecordBean`. But somehow it does not work.

Before I post my code, this post [(How to send selected date of richcalendar to my bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502280/how-to-send-selected-date-of-richcalendar-to-my-bean) is pretty much my problem. The solution has been to add a `onchange`attribute to `rich:calendar` which I did. It didn't solve my issue.
The alternative solution discussed in this topic, submitting the calendar form with a `commandButton` does work, but I'd really like to use the `onchange` attribute.

There is no error message or any other output so I don't have a clue why it does not work.

This is my code:

```
 <f:view>
    <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Datum: " for="dateNew" />
            <rich:calendar value="#{newTimeRecordBean.selectedDate}"
            onchange="changeSelectedDate()"
            showApplyButton="true" 
            id="dateNew"
            locale="de"
            popup="true"
            datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
            cellWidth="24px" 
            cellHeight="22px" 
            style="width:200px"
              />
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

This is my managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NewTimeRecordBean {
    private String selectedDate;

    public String getSelectedDate()
    {
        return selectedDate;
    }

    public void setSelectedDate(String selectedDate)
    {
        this.selectedDate = selectedDate;
    }

    public void changeSelectedDate()
    {
         System.out.println("Changed Date: "+getSelectedDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: ` somehow it does not work` Any error message to give us ? Or can you describe what happens ?

Comment: No there is no output that could give me a hint what is happening.

Comment: Change `onchange="changeSelectedDate()"` to `onchange="#{newTimeRecordBean.changeSelectedDate}"`

Comment: with this I am getting an error: `The class 'NewTimeRecordBean' does not have the property 'changeSelectedDate`.

Comment: @Jbartmann describe what are you doing with the calendar and what do you expect to happen.

Comment: Is changeSelectedDate() mentioned in onchange attribute a JS method? or Are you trying to use the method from NewTimeRecordBean?